# Program which given a list of length n finds all triplets i, j and k with i <= j such that a[i] * a[j] = a[k]

Tags: java, big-o

I'm trying to figure out how I can write a program such that a list of length `n` finds all triplets `i`, `j` and `k` with `i <= j` such that `a[i] * a[j] = a[k]` and return the amount of times this happens. The obvious solution is a triple for loop giving it a runtime of O(n^3) like this.

```java
public static int count(int[] a) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] <= a[j]) {
                for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
                    if (a[i] * a[j] == a[k])
                        total++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

But I came up with a faster way using hashsets like so.

```java
public static int count(int[] a) { // O(n^2)
    int total = 0;
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i : a) { // O(n)
        set.add(i); // O(1)
    }
    for (int i : a) { // O(n^2)
        for (int j : a) {
            if (i <= j) {
                if (set.contains(i * j)) // O(1)
                    total++;
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

This has the runtime of O(n^2). Is it possible to get it faster then this?

Comment: I don't think you can. You need to check every combination since any of them might be part of the solution. I guess you can put specific logic in there if the list is sorted and if there are not negative numbers, but is that worth the effort?

Comment: sorting the list would have a complexity of O(n log(n)) if that helps :)

Comment: Did you mean `a[i] <= a[j]` or `i <= j` which you mentioned in the question.

Comment: I ment a[i] <= a[j]. i and j are just elements in the array.